# Can't find servlet in jetty

Tags: forms, servlets, jetty, web.xml

I am really struggling to figure out why I can't get to my servlet when submit my form. I have tried changing the path in the xml multiple times and edited the servlet code, but my browser still can't find my servlet when I submit the form.

Here is the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app>


<servlet>
<servlet-name>quizServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>quiz</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>quizServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/quiz</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

I have also tried having form3/quiz be the url-pattern.

Here is the simple servlet:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

    public class quiz extends HttpServlet {
        public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
        {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        String grade = request.getParameter("grade");
        out.println("grade=" + grade);
        out.println("</body></html>");
        out.close();
    }

}
```

And here is the html:

```
<html>
<body>
Quiz
<form method='post' action='quiz'>
    grade<input type='text' name='grade'>
<input type='submit'></form>
</body>
</html>
```

index.html is contained in webapps/simpleForms/form3, web.xml is in webapps/simpleForms/form3/WEB-INF and quiz.java is in webapps/simpleForms/form3/WEB-INF/classes and is compiled.

Comment: What happens if you try to hit `http://localhost:8080/simpleForms/quiz` ?

Comment: Your `web.xml` has no spec version or xsd/dtd specified, this can result in an undetermined servlet behavior mode.  Your class names are also out of spec (encourage you to use a package AND a class that starts with a capitol letter).

Answer (score 0):

your folder structure is having problem.I am able to run code provided by you.

- if your project name is `webapps`,then keep your servlets in
  `src`(webapps/src/quiz) folder.Organize them using package if you want.
- keep your html in `WebContent` folder(webapp/WebContent/yourHtml.html)
- keep `web.xml` under
  WebContent/WEB-INF(webapp/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml)

With this folder structure,you should be able to run your servlet code.